# How to design a Injection type textfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am coding a doctor app in which LogIn has this number text field in the form of injection and I don't know how to create it. This is the design [I need to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqvyE.png)

I want to know how to code it. Is there any way to do it or so !?

Comment: Please show every attempt that you tried.

Comment: You could use a [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget in order to set the injection in the background and the text field in the foreground at the needed position

Comment: Hi! In its current state this question isn't particularly great. But that's okay! Take a read of [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), come back, and improve your question. A few highlighted points: 1) SO is not a code writing service! Show us what you've tried, where you've researched, and why it hasn't worked. We won't do your work for you ;) 2) In regards to Flutter there are loads of online learning resources. Check em out! 3) Show a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when what you've tried doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

--> if you can need a same textFormFiled so you can use custom painter widgets  to create this types of textFormFiled.

--> if you can not create proper this types of ui in a textFormFiled so its a not possible in a flutter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create this type of textfield it is possible in flutter

1. firstly you have to take image of injection
2. then use **stack** widget and on stack first widget will your injection image and then you can add textform filed